# ./src/views/users/UserCreate.js Attempted import error: 'email' is not exported from './../validations'

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I Have an react app with the following tree:

```
src/
--/views
  --validations.js
  --/users
    --UserCreate.js
```

My validations.js code:

```
import {
    required,
    minLength,
    maxLength,
    minValue,
    maxValue,
    number,
    regex,
    email,
    choices
} from 'react-admin';

export const required = () => required("Campo obrigatório")
export const minLength = (value) => minLength(value,"Este campo deve ter o minimo de "+value+" caracteres")
export const maxLength = (value) => maxLength("Este campo deve ter o máximo de "+value+" caracteres")
export const email = () => email("Digite um e-mail válido")
export const passwordsMatch = (value, allValues) => value !== allValues.password ? 'As senhas não coincidem' : undefined;
```

My UserCreate.js code like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Create, SimpleForm, TextInput, DisabledInput } from 'react-admin';
import { required, email, minLength,maxLength } from './../validations';


export const UserCreate = props => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm redirect="list">
            <DisabledInput label="#" source="id" />
            <TextInput source="name" validate={[required(),minLength(5),maxLength(20)]} label="Nome"/>
            <TextInput source="email" validate={[required(),minLength(5),maxLength(20),email()]} label="E-mail"/>
            <TextInput source="password" validate={[required(),minLength(8),maxLength(20)]} label="Senha" type="password"/>
            <TextInput name="confirm_password" validate={[passwordsMatch]} label="Confirmar senha" type="password"/>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
)
```

But, on run i getting the following error:

`./src/views/users/UserCreate.js
Attempted import error: 'email' is not exported from './../validations'.`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think there could be name conflict happening with word 'email'.
react-admin also have 'email' while you are exporting a const 'email'. Can you try some other name with your constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're importing `email` and declaring a constant called `email` as well.

That's making a conflict in your code and it's taking the first `email` from the module `react-admin` which is not exported.

You should change the name of your const in order to make it work.